# is spring 4.3.17 RELEASE compatible with hibernate core 5.2.16.FINAL? Because I get error

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, java-8

I am using spring 4.3.17 RELEASE with Hibernate 5.2.16.FINAL and java8
pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Platform</name>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${internal.dep.groupId.1}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${internal.dep.artifactId.1}</artifactId>
            <version>${internal.dep.version.1}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${internal.dep.groupId.1}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${internal.dep.artifactId.1}</artifactId>
            <version>${internal.dep.version.1}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>string</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.5-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.oracle.jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
            <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I get an error :

```
[ERROR] failed org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@4cb00fa5{/platform,/home/vf-root/project/blueprint-platform/src/main/webapp}
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:330)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:241)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSession(HibernateDaoSupport.java:177)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSession(HibernateDaoSupport.java:148)
        at com.vodafone.global.blueprint.backend.dao.SchemaVersionDao.getMetadataListFromDB(SchemaVersionDao.java:95)
        at com.vodafone.global.blueprint.backend.dao.SchemaVersionDao.getMetadata(SchemaVersionDao.java:38)
        at com.vodafone.global.blueprint.backend.dao.SchemaVersionDao.getMetadataHashCodeFromDB(SchemaVersionDao.java:107)
        at com.vodafone.global.blueprint.backend.listeners.HealthCheck.isSchemaOk(HealthCheck.java:56)
        at com.vodafone.global.blueprint.backend.listeners.HealthCheck.contextInitialized(HealthCheck.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1239)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:466)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:124)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:441)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:383)
        at
```

In the error the error message mentions hibernate3 whereas I have mentioned hibernate4 in applicationContext.xml
how to make the application use hibernate4 instead of hibernate3?

In the error the error message mentions hibernate3 whereas I have mentioned hibernate4 in applicationContext.xml
how to make the application use hibernate4 instead of hibernate3?

In the error the error message mentions hibernate3 whereas I have mentioned hibernate4 in applicationContext.xml
how to make the application use hibernate4 instead of hibernate3?

In the error the error message mentions hibernate3 whereas I have mentioned hibernate4 in applicationContext.xml
how to make the application use hibernate4 instead of hibernate3?